# i have download discord package but its not working in vscode

Tags: python, import, discord.py

I have download discord in command prompt but when I type import discord in vscode it cant find the file. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. What do i do?
If i run a code this pops up

No module named 'discord'

Comment: did you use `pip install ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either forgot to add python to the path or are using the wrong environment.
**[image: strong text]**

while installing python, this option pops up.
or you simply are using the wrong environment.
[image]

[image]

[image]

above, in the environment select the python version you will be using (in the existing environment tab)

if your issue was with you not adding python to the path, after doing so, you have to run `pip install discord` again. If you are unsure about "if" you have added python to the path or not, simply open your cmd prompt and type `python` to check so. If it looks like the one below, then it is added to the path.

hope that helps

also, don't forget to import the following:

```
import discord
import discord.utils
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow! Please post your current code or errors from the terminal, not just telling one error that could solve everything. As I presume it is only the error from importing Discord, here are some troubleshoot options.

Installing Discord.py in cmd prompt

```
pip install discord
```

importing Discord into your python code, these are the main Discord imports

```
import discord
import discord.utils
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```

Your python version is under date

Or your compiler is not linked, pip must be in your PATH directory, you can change this in settings, environmental paths, then finding pip in your python folder. (Usually located at C:\Program Files\Python).

If not, uninstall python and try get the most up to date version, hope this helps you.

Comment: as you are using VSC, environments can be installed, which basically works as pip does, VSC has their own package installer